# Apache-commons-net Illegal (yet legal) CIDR notation

Tags: java, networking, apache-commons-net, cidr

I need the ability to work with CIDR notation in Java.

I found the commons library SubnetUtils.

When I try to use a CIDR of 10.10.0.0/22, as an example I get the following

`Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not parse [10.10.0.0]
    at org.apache.commons.net.util.SubnetUtils.calculate(SubnetUtils.java:240)
    at org.apache.commons.net.util.SubnetUtils.<init>(SubnetUtils.java:52)`

The code that is calling is:

`SubnetUtils subnetUtils = new SubnetUtils(cidrNotation);
 SubnetInfo info = subnetUtils.getInfo();`

I see that SubnetUtils is checking the bits to see if the mask is valid.

`   From SubnetUtils.java

```
 private void calculate(String mask) {
    Matcher matcher = cidrPattern.matcher(mask);

    if (matcher.matches()) {
        address = matchAddress(matcher);

        /* Create a binary netmask from the number of bits specification /x */
        int cidrPart = rangeCheck(Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(5)), 0, NBITS);
        for (int j = 0; j < cidrPart; ++j) {
            netmask |= (1 << 31-j);
        }

        /* Calculate base network address */
        network = (address & netmask);

        /* Calculate broadcast address */
        broadcast = network | ~(netmask);
    } else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Could not parse [" + mask + "]");
    }
```

`

I realize 10.0.0.0/8 is a class A, but I should legally be able to chop it into smaller pieces.

Is there a way around this?  A better Utility?  Or am I stuck rewriting SubnetUtils?

Comment: You seem to be assuming that the issue is `/22` instead of `/8`. Have you checked the source code to see what the library is actually complaining about? I'm not sure the library is complaining about what you think it's complaining about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I continued to investigate and it turns out that deep in the recursion I lost the mask on my CIDR.  the first number of passes was ok then in an exception path it was lost.  The utility works as expected.